# vBulletin making an extra login page

Tags: vbulletin, login-script

A couple of my users have a problem with the current popup login on my vBulletin board: 4.2.1.

How can I make another separate page with just the login which will allow them to login and get back on the board properly?

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$curdir = getcwd();
#Add your root dir below where it says "ADD ROOT" Example: /home/server/public_html/mainsite/forums
#Do not end with a "/" leave it open like above example.
chdir('');

require_once('global.php');
chdir($curdir);
if ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] == 0) {
#Form Display Code, You can edit the way the Form is layed out here.
  echo "<form id=\"login\" action=\"http://YOURSITE.BLAH/login.php?do=login\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf, 0)\">
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://YOURSITE.BLAH/clientscript/vbulletin_md5.js?v=364\"></script>
<label for=\"navbar_username\">Username</label>
<input type=\"text\" class=\"bginput\" style=\"font-size: 11px\" name=\"vb_login_username\" id=\"navbar_username\" size=\"10\" accesskey=\"u\" tabindex=\"101\" onfocus=\"if (this.value == 'User Name') this.value = '';\" />
<label for=\"navbar_password\">Password</label>
<input type=\"password\" class=\"bginput\" style=\"font-size: 11px\" name=\"vb_login_password\" id=\"navbar_password\" size=\"10\" tabindex=\"102\" />
<label for=\"cb_cookieuser_navbar\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cookieuser\" value=\"1\" tabindex=\"103\" id=\"cb_cookieuser_navbar\" accesskey=\"c\" />Remember Me?</label>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"s\" value=\"\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"do\" value=\"login\" />";
?>
<input type="hidden" name="url" value ="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
<?php
echo "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"button\" value=\"Login\" tabindex=\"104\" title=\"Enter your username and password in the boxes provided to login, or click the 'register' button to create a profile for yourself.\" accesskey=\"s\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"vb_login_md5password\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"vb_login_md5password_utf\" />
</form>";
#End Form Display Code
} else {
#Display after login completed
  echo "Welcome Back, <b>".$vbulletin->userinfo['username']."</b>";
  if ($vbulletin->userinfo['usergroupid'] == '6' ) {
  echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href=\"/forums/member.php?1-".$vbulletin->userinfo['username']."\">My Profile</a>";
  echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href=\"/forums/admincp/index.php\">AdminCP</a>";
  echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href=\"/forums/modcp/index.php\">ModCP</a>";
  }
}
?>
```

That does the trick :) Just put that in a php file and open it!